# how to find the number of records that has values between 0 and 50 in python

Tags: python

i am trying to the number of records but i keep getting 0

```
with open('C:/Users/m/Desktop/NA/Project 2/Project-2/titanic-data.csv', 'rb') as t:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(t)
    titanic_values = list(reader)


count = 0
fare = []
for titanic in titanic_values:
    fare.append(titanic['Fare'])
    if '0' <= fare <= '50':
        count = count+1
```

Comment: `fare` is a list.  It makes no sense to compare a list to a string.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a type cast:

```
0 <= int(fare) <= 50
```

That does an integer comparison and not a string comparison like in the original case.

But come to think of it, fare is a *list*, so what exactly are you up to?

You probably want:

```
sum(1 for titanic in titanic_values if 0 <= int(titanic['Fare']) <= 50)
```

Or:

```
sum((0 <= int(titanic['Fare']) <= 50) for titanic in titanic_values)
```